# IonNav is not working with react 18 or ionic 6

Tags: reactjs, ionic-react, ionic6

> here im using IonNav.
> import { IonNav } from "@ionic/react";
> im getting blank screen with IonNav

```js
return(
       <IonPage>
        <IonNav className="nav">
          <div>
            <h1>Please help</h1>
          </div>
        </IonNav>
      </IonPage>
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it to the root callback

```
 return (
    <IonNav
      root={() => (
        <div>
          <h1>Please asd</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    ></IonNav>
  );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vytfp1-5pkrwm?file=src%2Fmain.tsx,src%2Findex.tsx

Comment: but it  rendering my component multple times. Can you suggest me how can i handdle this.

Comment: seems to be an issue with IonRouterOutlet  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionapp-double-rendering/182745/3